# Using Boto to find to which device and EBS Volume is mounted

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-ebs

How do I find to which device an EBS Volume is mounted with Python Boto v2.0?

[boto.ec2.Volume](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/master/boto/ec2/volume.py) has some interesting properies like `attachment_state` and `volume_state`. But are there any functions for device mapping?

[boto.manage.volume](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/master/boto/manage/volume.py) has `get_device(self, params)` but requires a CommandLineGetter.

Any pointers on how to proceed or some samples of using `boto.manage`?

Answer (score 12):

I believe attach_data.device is what your looking for. part of volume.

Heres an example, not sure if this is the best way, but it outputs volumeid, instanceid, and attachment_data something like:

```
Attached Volume ID - Instance ID - Device Name
vol-12345678 - i-ab345678 - /dev/sdp
vol-12345678 - i-ab345678 - /dev/sda1
vol-12345678 - i-cd345678 - /dev/sda1


import boto
ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
res = ec2.get_all_instances()
instances = [i for r in res for i in r.instances]
vol = ec2.get_all_volumes()
def attachedvolumes():
    print 'Attached Volume ID - Instance ID','-','Device Name'
    for volumes in vol:
        if volumes.attachment_state() == 'attached':
            filter = {'block-device-mapping.volume-id':volumes.id}
            volumesinstance = ec2.get_all_instances(filters=filter)
            ids = [z for k in volumesinstance for z in k.instances]
            for s in ids:
                 print volumes.id,'-',s.id,'-',volumes.attach_data.device
# Get a list of unattached volumes           
def unattachedvolumes():
   for unattachedvol in vol:
       state = unattachedvol.attachment_state()
   if state == None:
        print unattachedvol.id, state
attachedvolumes()
unattachedvolumes()
```

Answer (score 9):

It isn't clear if you're running this from the instance itself or externally.  If the latter, you will not need the metadata call.  Just supply the instance id.

```
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
from boto.utils import get_instance_metadata

conn = EC2Connection()
m = get_instance_metadata()
volumes = [v for v in conn.get_all_volumes() if v.attach_data.instance_id == m['instance-id']]

print(volumes[0].attach_data.device)
```

Note that an instance may have multiple volumes, so robust code won't assume there's a single device.

Comment: @VincentTheeten If this solution was what you were looking for, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you also want the block device mappings (in linux, the local device name of the EBS volume), you can also use `EC2Connection.get_instance_attribute` to retrieve a list of the local device names and their corresponding EBS objects:

```
def get_block_device_mapping(instance_id):
    return conn.get_instance_attribute(
            instance_id=instance_id,
            attribute='blockDeviceMapping'
            )['blockDeviceMapping']
```

This will return a dictionary with local device names as keys, and EBS objects as values (from which you can get all sorts of things like the volume-id).

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found is to get all resources in one region at a time and associate them yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import boto.ec2

REGION = 'us-east'
CONN = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(REGION)

def main():
    volumes = conn.get_all_volumes()

    for volume in volumes:
        print volume

        # Match to an instance id
        print volume.attach_data.instance_id

        # # Object attributes:
        # print volume.__dict__

        # # Object methods:
        # print(dir(volume))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```